# C# chaining methods using streams

Tags: c#

I have two different objects in c# that expose methods using streams.

One of them exposes a method that takes a Stream as a parameter and writes to the stream, while the other exposes a method that takes a Stream as a parameter and reads from it.

Writing stuff to a MemoryStream is out of the question as there is too much data to keep completely in memory. Is there a way I can somehow chain these two methods, or do I have to manually write an adaptor of some kind to go in between myself?

Edit:

one of the methods looks like this, which serializes the object to a stream:

```
object1.WriteToStream(Stream s)
```

while the other looks like this:

```
object2.Process(Stream input, Stream output)
```

The second method reads from the input stream, processes the data and writes it to another stream. My problem is that I need to use the 2nd method to process the data generated by the `WriteToStream` method of the first object.

Comment: Would you please send us your code?

Comment: Please show some example code.

Comment: why not create a result object ? to it you can add methods to process its internal attributes. you would benefit scalability and simplicity for future maintainers

Comment: You need some kind of buffer unless you rewrite both methods to work simultaneously. The `MemoryStream` still would be your best option. If your only concern is not keeping the data in memory, you could of course use a filestream instead.

Comment: MemoryStream wouldn't work as there is too much data (gigabytes). And writing it to an intermediate file wouldn't work for me either as part of the processing done is compression and writing it to a file. Having an intermediate file would more than double my disk space requirements temporarily.

Comment: So where do you expect the data to be until you continue to the next step? Not in memory, not on disk, ... you are running low on options with this approach. Can the methods be parallelized (Producer-Consumer Pattern) or do they need to run synchronous? Can you even change the two methods or didn't you write them yourself?

Comment: I'm asking whether there's a way to make the streams, you know, stream data. Yes I know there needs to be some kind of buffer in between. I'm asking whether anything like that is available in c# or whether anything like that is available elsewhere online that I haven't managed to find.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475747/is-there-an-in-memory-stream-that-blocks-like-a-file-stream

Comment: @CedricMamo If the methods in question *actually* stream the data then you won't have any problem using a memory stream, as it would only need to actually hold a small buffer of data in memory.  If the producer doesn't actually stream its content, and instead won't return until it has written all of its data to the stream, then it doesn't matter what type of stream you use, you can't actually stream the data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have a possibility to "chain" the two methods.
But there are some prerequisite:

- The output stream (the parameter of write stream) must be global, or reachable from both function.
- The both function but be run on different thread, to run it synchronously. use [Task.Run()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2) or a different [Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- To synchronize this to thread you can use [Semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netframework-4.7.2)

And here are sample code to do it. But this is not working code, it is just a skeleton

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Example
{
    // A semaphore that simulates a limited resource pool.
    //
    private static Semaphore _pool;

    // A padding interval to make the output more orderly.
    private static int _padding;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a semaphore that can satisfy up to three
        // concurrent requests. Use an initial count of zero,
        // so that the entire semaphore count is initially
        // owned by the main program thread.
        _pool = new Semaphore(0, 2);

        Thread threadWrite = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(WriterThread));
        Thread threadRead = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ReadThread));

        threadWrite.Start(commonStream);
        threadRead.Start(commonStream);

        // Wait for half a second, to allow all the
        // threads to start and to block on the semaphore.
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        // The main thread starts out holding the entire
        // semaphore count. Calling Release(3) brings the 
        // semaphore count back to its maximum value, and
        // allows the waiting threads to enter the semaphore,
        // up to three at a time.
        //
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread calls Release(3).");
        _pool.Release(3);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits.");
    }

    private static void WriterThread(object objStream)
    {
        Stream stream = (Stream)objStream;
        while (true)
        {
            // lock the semaphore, because you want to write the stream
            _pool.WaitOne();

            // your code goes here, to write the stream to some data, but not all 

            //release the pool, to indicate to the other thread, there are data in stream 
            _pool.Release();


            if (IsAllDataWritten)
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void ReadThread(object objStream)
    {
        Stream stream = (Stream)objStream;
        while (true)
        {
            // lock the semaphore, because you want to write the stream
            _pool.WaitOne();

            // your code goes here, to read and process the stream data

            //release the pool, to indicate to the other thread, there are data in stream 
            _pool.Release();


            if (AllDataIsReaded )
                break;
        }
    }
}
```