# How do I post large ammount of bytes that I recieve from network to a web server?

Tags: c#, http, request, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Hi I have a binary data that I recieve from network connection I have, I would like to sending those data in a HttpClient post.

So far I have created this example which does not work

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamContent content = new StreamContent(outputStream);
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/v1/media/frames");
    request.Content = content;

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

    while (true)
    {
        await outputStream.WriteAsync(new byte[4] { 4, 4, 4, 4 }, 0, 4);
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

This does not work and it seems that it does not work because I'm writing data to a memory stream after I send post. Is there a way to do that? The only think I can think of is to implement my own stream which will block reading until there is something to read... Is there something similar in .net?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You seem to have two problems: 1. MemoryStream will reach the end. 2. You're awaiting the `Send`, so it never moves beyond that (by the time you get a response, your request has been fully received).

Comment: The server is also mine so I'm able to send header before reading the content (that is why I'm using HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead). The first problem is the only problem I have :)

Comment: Since you have no replies, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475747/is-there-an-in-memory-stream-that-blocks-like-a-file-stream) might help.